# HTTP Caching Last Modified

Tags: http

I am trying to achieve the following: 
- Make the browser validate cache headers, and on change - update the cache with the newer version from the server.

The problem is that I have a website with css/js being often updated, but expire time set to 1 week which means users need 1 week to see the new changes. What I am trying to achieve is to tell the browser that there is a modification on this file (last-modified + etag) so that it should update it's cache. However, testing this on Chrome did not work exactly as planned. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: enabling last-modified and etag headers

Comment: show us some sample code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: http://s30.postimg.org/68vm45hkh/sample.jpg - Here you can see the server responds with 200, instead of 304.

Comment: do not post images, they are often blocked over (c) networks

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Damn Apache v2.4.7 bug - disable the ETag header, and it is all fine.